# Any way to return only (clean) text from a Wikipedia article?

Tags: java, formatting, wikipedia

My overall goal is to return only clean sentences from a Wikipedia article without any markup. Obviously, there are ways to return JSON, XML, etc., but these are full of markup. My best approach so far is to return what Wikipedia calls `raw`. For example, the following link returns the `raw` format for the page "Iron Man":

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Iron%20Man&action=raw

Here is a snippet of what is returned:

```
...//I am truncating some markup at the beginning here. 
|creative_team_month =
|creative_team_year =
|creators_series =
|TPB =
|ISBN =
|TPB# =
|ISBN# =
|nonUS =
}}
'''Iron Man''' is a fictional character, a [[superhero]] that appears in\\
[[comic book]]s published by [[Marvel Comics]]. 
...//I am truncating here everything until the end.
```

I have stuck to the `raw` format because I have found it the easiest to clean up. Although what I have written so far in Java cleans up this pretty well, there are a lot of cases that slip by. These cases include markup for Wikipedia timelines, Wikipedia pictures, and other Wikipedia properties which do not appear on *all* articles. Again, I am working in Java (in particular, I am working on a Tomcat web application).

**Question: Is there a better way to get clean, human-readable sentences from Wikipedia articles? Maybe someone already built a library for this which I just can't find?**

I will be happy to edit my question to provide details about what I mean by clean and human-readable if it is not clear.

My current Java method which cleans up the `raw` formatted text is as follows:

```
public String cleanRaw(String input){
    //Next three lines attempt to get rid of references.
    input= input.replaceAll("<ref>.*?</ref>","");
    input= input.replaceAll("<ref .*?</ref>","");
    input= input.replaceAll("<ref .*?/>","");

    input= input.replaceAll("==[^=]*==", "");
    //I found that anything between curly braces is not needed. 
    while (input.indexOf("{{") >= 0){
        int prevLength= input.length();
        input= input.replaceAll("\\{\\{[^{}]*\\}\\}", "");
        if (prevLength == input.length()){
            break;
        }
    }
    //Next line gets rid of links to other Wikipedia pages.
    input= input.replaceAll("\\[\\[([^]]*[|])?([^]]*?)\\]\\]", "$2");
    input= input.replaceAll("<!--.*?-->","");
    input= input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9., ]", "");

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any of these: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: I haven't seen these. If you are familiar with them, can you suggest one I should try first?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452102/how-to-get-plain-text-out-of-wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a couple of projects that might help.  You might be able to run the first one by including a Javascript engine in your Java code.

**txtwiki.js**
A javascript library to convert MediaWiki markup to plaintext.
https://github.com/joaomsa/txtwiki.js

**WikiExtractor**
A Python script that extracts and cleans text from a Wikipedia database dump
http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor

Source:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: "You might be able to run the first one by including a Javascript engine in your Java code." -- Or simply implement the JS in Java; at a glance, it doesn't appear to be particularly complicated or utilize anything unique to JS.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at these (and come back to accept your answer if more straightforward answers haven't been posted).

Comment: how did you get on?  Would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you.