# How can i get a list from a html file with only countries in it using grep and sed?

Tags: bash, sed, html-table, grep

I downloaded this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states and I want to extract a list with only countries in it.

I downloaded the whole html in a file named countries.

```
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states >countries
```

I found that all the countries are after a `span id = ....` so I tried to search after those using `grep -F span id countries`

But how can i filter the results with sed ?

My problem is, I do not really understand how grep and sed work together the manualpages are not that good for a beginner and the internet is really not that helpful I hope you can help me.

Comment: You need an HTML parser.

Comment: Depends whether it it is a one-off thing or something you will do regularly. If you do it regularly, then I agree, use a proper HTML parser, because html format is not hard fixed. However good your sed skills 6 months down the line someone will make an edit and your sed script will break in unusual ways. If it is one-off, just load the file into your favourite visual editor or spreadsheet, break it into lines by splitting on a convenient character (eg >), then just do search/replace on the file until you get what you want.

Comment: Google xmlstarlet. For other applications - if you're considering using grep+sed then you should be using just awk instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get plain text out of wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452102/how-to-get-plain-text-out-of-wikipedia)

Comment: With grep and sed, like asked for: grep -Po '<span id="\w+">' countries | sed -nr 's/<span id="(\w+)">/\1/p'

Use | (pipe) to redirect output from one command to another.

Some countries missing from command output, because they are not in <span id="country name">.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `grep` or `sed` to parse XML or HTML. If you really want to use a regular expression tester like [regex101](https://regex101.com/). But before you do so read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) first.

Try this:

```
xmllint --shell <<<'cat //tr/td[1]/descendant::span[@class="flagicon"]/following-sibling::a[@title]/text()' --html countries 2>/dev/null |
recode html..utf8 |
sort -u |
sed '/^[ /]/d'
```

Comment: Not all countries are output by that, e.g. Scotland and Greenland are missing since they appear in a different section of the table presumably, but it's a great start!

Comment: @EdMorton Scotland is not independent, it is part of the UK. I took just the first column with `td[1]`.

Comment: Being Scottish myself, I'm aware of my country's status as stated in that article: `The United Kingdom is a Commonwealth realm[e] consisting of four constituent countries: England, Northern Ireland, Scotland, and Wales.`. Yes, I understand that's what you did, I understand why you did it, and like I said it's a great start.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/<td style="vertical-align:top;">.*title[^"]*"([^"(]*)( \([^)]*\))*".*/\1/p' countriesFile
```

This solution represents the 206 listed states in the table.