# Parse wikitext myself with python - KeyError: 'revisions'

Tags: python, text, wikipedia, keyerror, data-extraction

I'm python newbie. I took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452102/how-to-get-plain-text-out-of-wikipedia) but i get this KeyError:
I just want to mention that it worked so I do not know what happened.

```
wikicode = page['revisions'][0]['*']
KeyError: 'revisions'
```

this is the code, thank you for any help!

```
def request_wiki_value(title=None, sentence=''):
if title is None:
    title = input("No title entered.\nPlease enter a title: ")
import requests
import mwparserfromhell
response = requests.get(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    params={
        'action': 'query',
        'format': 'json',
        'titles': title,
        'prop': 'revisions',
        'rvprop': 'content',
    }
).json()
page = next(iter(response['query']['pages'].values()))
wikicode = page['revisions'][0]['*']
parsed_wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(wikicode)
# open("article.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8').write(parsed_wikicode.strip_code())
for ch in parsed_wikicode.strip_code():
    sentence = sentence + ch
    if ch == '\n':
        sentence = sentence.removesuffix(ch)
        open("article.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8').write(sentence)
        sentence = ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import requests
import mwparserfromhell
def request_wiki_value(title=None, sentence=''):
  if title is None:
      title = input("No title entered.\nPlease enter a title: ")

  response = requests.get(
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
      params={
          'action': 'query',
          'format': 'json',
          'titles': title,
          'prop': 'revisions',
          'rvprop': 'content',
      }
  ).json()
  page = next(iter(response['query']['pages'].values()))
  wikicode = page['revisions'][0]['*']
  parsed_wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(wikicode)
  # open("article.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8').write(parsed_wikicode.strip_code())
  for ch in parsed_wikicode.strip_code():
      sentence = sentence + ch
      if ch == '\n':
          sentence = sentence.removesuffix(ch)
          open("article.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8').write(sentence)
          sentence = ''
```

The problem is you did not add indent for the function body