# How to get Wikipedia content as text by API?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get Wikipedia pages as text.

I looked at the Wikipedia API from here https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php which says that in order to get pages as text I need to append this to a page address:

```
api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=txt
```

However, when I try appending this suffix to a normal page's address, the page is not found:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=txt
```

Following the instructions from [Get Text Content from mediawiki page via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625162/get-text-content-from-mediawiki-page-via-api), I tried `adding /api.php?action=parse&page=test` to the end of the query string. Therefore, I obtained this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington/api.php?action=parse&page=test
```

However, this doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Text Content from mediawiki page via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625162/get-text-content-from-mediawiki-page-via-api)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did you actually read the instructions you linked to?

Answer (score 3):

**NB**: All this examples are CORS enabled.

---

**Text only**

From the precise title, as seen in [the wikipedia page url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokolsky_Opening):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=Sokolsky_Opening&format=json

---

**Search relevant pages by keywords**

Get IDs, get precise titles/url, get some quick text extract;

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&format=json&exsentences=1&origin=*&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=search&gsrlimit=23&gsrsearch=chess

---

**Wiki page ID**

Using the precise title:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=pageprops&format=json&titles=Sokolsky_Opening

---

**Full html**

By wiki page ID, includes the [*Wikitext*](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&origin=*&format=json&pageid=100017

---

**Stripped html**

Lighter html version, without the [*Wikitext*](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext).

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&format=json&titles=Sokolsky_Opening

---

**Cross origin:**

About using CORS requests, sometimes it may require 2 calls to the API,  to jump between ID and page title.

In a ssl context, we can use fetch to embed some wiki text anywhere.

Example remote [.json](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&explaintext&format=json&titles=Sokolsky_Opening).

```js
fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&explaintext&format=json&titles=Sokolsky_Opening").then(v => v.json()).then((function(v){
    main.innerHTML = v["query"]["pages"]["100017"]["extract"]
    })
  )
```

```html
<pre id="main" style="white-space: pre-wrap"></pre>
```

---

⚠️ This API has some quirks, some pages with heavy contents get truncated sometimes, among other things and possible rate limiting.

---

Good luck.

---

Comment: can you please add what each parameter does exactly?

Comment: The api documentation is a little bit of a mess, you have to modify the url as example this is the doc for `action=query` https://mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query

Comment: yea I know it's a mess that's why I'm here :) I was looking for how exactly your first example ended up as mostly plaintext with most of the markup removed. It seems that's the `prop=extracts&explaintext` `extracts` gives minimel HTML and `explaintext` removes the HTML from that

Comment: This is the only notes I have, but it looks like this https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts ? Otherwise look here all params are detailed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some of [these formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php): `json`, `jsonfm`, `none`, `php`, `phpfm`, `rawfm`, `xml` or `xmlfm`, so `txt` is not valid format. Also your API link is wrong, use this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=George_Washington&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml
```