# How can I extract all sections of a Wikipedia page in plain text?

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I have the following code in python, which extracts only the introduction of the article on "Artificial Intelligence", while instead I would like to extract all sub-sections (History, Goals ...)

```
import requests

def get_wikipedia_page(page_title):
  endpoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
  params = {
    "format": "json",
    "action": "query",
    "prop": "extracts",
    "exintro": "",
    "explaintext": "",
    "titles": page_title
  }
  response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
  data = response.json()
  pages = data["query"]["pages"]
  page_id = list(pages.keys())[0]
  return pages[page_id]["extract"]

page_title = "Artificial intelligence"
wikipedia_page = get_wikipedia_page(page_title)
```

Someone proposed to use another approach that parses html and uses BeautifulSoup to convert to text:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in 
line.split("  
"))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

This is not a good-enough solution, as it includes all text that appears on the website (like image text), and it includes citations in the text (e.g. [1]), while the first script removes them.

I suspect that the api of wikipedia should offer a more elegant solution, it would be rather weird if one can get only the first section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Retrieving Wikipedia pages as HTML

Like in our web-browsers we can retrieve the complete Wikipedia page by URL and parse the HTML response with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

### Wikepedia's API

As alternative we can use the API, see [Wikipedia's API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#API_documentation).

#### Extract plain-text

When using the `action=query` with `format=json` you can use these 4 options for text-extraction:

- `titles=Artificial intelligence` for the page
- `prop=extracts` use the *TextExtracts* extension
- `exintro` limits the response to content before the first section heading (**remove this to get entire text incl. sections**)
- `explaintext` extracts as plain-text response instead of HTML

Example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Artificial%20intelligence&prop=extracts&explaintext

#### Get each section separately

To retrieve the sections use the `action=parse` with `format=json` and those options:

- `page=Artificial intelligence` get contents for this page
- `prop=sections` only return sections

There is also an **API sandbox** where you can try several parameters.
The resulting GET request will retrieve all the sections of example page "Artificial intelligence":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Artificial%20intelligence&prop=sections&formatversion=2

This will respond with a JSON containing all sections:

```json
{
    "parse": {
        "title": "Artificial intelligence",
        "pageid": 1164,
        "sections": [
            {
                "toclevel": 1,
                "level": "2",
                "line": "History",
                "number": "1",
                "index": "1",
                "fromtitle": "Artificial_intelligence",
                "byteoffset": 5987,
                "anchor": "History",
                "linkAnchor": "History"
            }
}
```

(simplified, only first section kept)

To get the text of one of those sections, specify the section as query-parameter (by id or title), e.g.  `section=1&sectiontitle=History`:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Artificial_intelligence&section=1&sectiontitle=History&formatversion=2

This retrieves the text (in HTML format):

```
{
    "parse": {
        "title": "Artificial intelligence",
        "pageid": 1164,
        "revid": 1126677096,
        "text": "<div class=\"mw-parser-output\"><h2><span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"History\">History</span><span class=\"mw-editsection\"><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">[</span><a href=\"/w/index.php?title=Artificial_intelligence&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1\" title=\"Edit section: History\">edit</a><span class=\"mw-editsection-bracket\">]</span></span></h2>\n<style data-mw-deduplicate=\"TemplateStyles:r1033289096\">.mw-parser-output .hatnote{font-style:italic}.mw-parser-output div.hatnote{padding-left:1.6em;margin-bottom:0.5em}.mw-parser-output .hatnote i{font-style:normal}.mw-parser-output .hatnote+link+.hatnote{margin-top:-0.5em}</style><div role=\"note\" class=\"hatnote navigation-not-searchable\">Main articles: <a href=\"/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence\" title=\"History of artificial intelligence\">History of artificial intelligence</a> and <a href=\"/wiki/Timeline_of_artificial_intelligence\" title=\"Timeline of artificial intelligence\">Timeline of artificial intelligence</a>
```

Note: above response was cut-off to only show a sample of the text.

Although above text contents is formatted as HTML, there might be options to get it as plain-text.

#### See also

- [Get Text Content from mediawiki page via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625162/get-text-content-from-mediawiki-page-via-api/21844127#21844127)
- [How to get plain text out of Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452102/how-to-get-plain-text-out-of-wikipedia)

### Python code

You can also use Python like

1. package [`wikipedia`](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/):

```py
import wikpedia

wikipedia.set_lang('en')
page = wikipedia.page('Artificial intelligence')
print(page.content)
```

2. a Gist from
   Sai Kumar Yava (scionoftech) using `requests`:
   [A small Python Code to get Wikipedia page content in plain text](https://gist.github.com/scionoftech/0f35d5e231be2cf46823d774023268b6)

Comment: thank you for all the info! the solution with the wikipedia package worked like a charm. also removing the "exintro" argument in my script did the job, as this asks the api to return only text before the first section